# sylius installation issue PHP Fatal error:

Tags: failed-installation, sylius

Please help.

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 
'/home/roberto/sylius/app/bootstrap.php.cache' 
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/roberto/sylius/app/console on line
 15
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you install Sylius? You should use Composer which will run bootstrap file generation script.